# Is arguing about "death sentence" in a dichotomic way a formal error?

Tags: logic, social-ethics

Often people are trying to show that death sentence is good and useful, while some other are arguing to show the opposite.

But reality is complex. If we would like to describe it with a mathematical model we would use a differential system of vectorial equations with many many variables. Saying if it is ethical or not is like trying to define a function from R^n to {bad,good}. It's stronger than a linearization, it's incredibly approssimative.

To make it clear with another example stating if death penalty is good or bad is like trying to say that the flow of images shown on a TV is black or white when it's made of some million of pixel each of which is taking one color between 16 millions and the image is changing 25 times a second.

Wouldn't be more productive to wonder on: "how can we prevent to reach a point where death penalty can be considered useful?"

**Is it possible to formally argue that my analogies are valid and thus it is not pragmatical to argue pro and against death penalty while it's** more pragmatical **to argue** on **how** could be possible to **avoid people to feel the need for it.**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking in your question: Are you asking whether it's possible to argue that the death penalty is a complicated issue from a formal, objective point of view? Or are you asking how one would make your analogies from a formal, objective point of view? Or is it something else?

Comment: @JamesKingsbery: The first one! I mean.. is it possible to argue that my analogies are valid and thus is not pragmatical to argue pro and against death penalty while it's more pragmatical to argue on how could be possible to avoid people to feel the need for it.

Comment: OK... Analogies are not normally arguments themselves, they simply help to describe an argument. It would be better to state your argument, use the analogy after the statement to make more clear what you mean, and then offer support... In that case though, your question is still would be closed because it is a "Am-I-right?" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noone is arguing that everyone guilty of any crime should be killed. Arguing that death penalty is *sometimes* appropriate is arguing *in favour of* death penalty, while arguing that it *never* is is arguing *against* it.

Per my understanding, your solution implies that death penalty is *sometimes* appropriate, but that we should avoid it whenever possible. I suppose many defenders of death penalty would agree with you.

Regarding the "formal, objective" aspect of your question: I don't think ethical questions can take an objective form (such as a valued field on the space of possible situations), at least not in our current state of knowledge. 
First you'd need a "space of possible situations" (in what language? The language of physics? Lots of complications here) and even then according to some ethical theories it would still be difficult or impossible (for example, if value judgments are contextual or requires a "moral sense").